# Best practices for editing data using forms in ms-access

Tags: forms, ms-access

So I've started learning access due to necessity, as the person who was in charge of it passed way and someone had to keep it going.
I noticed a very bad (at least IMO) behavior in all databases he created: Every single form was bound directly to a table or saved query. This way, if the user opened a form, he had to complete all the steps he was supposed to do, because if he closed the form mid process (or the computer froze, or anything of the sort), the actual data would be compromised as it would be half complete. This often times broke everything in the process chain, rendering sub-sequential steps impossible to be performed and forced me to correct data manually directly in the tables.

As I've start upgrading his stuff and developing my own, I've been trying to learn ways to allow the data to be edited in the form only, making it possible to cancel the process anytime or save the changes all at once in the end.

If the editions were simple, I discovered that I could create a recordset, copy relevant data to unbound fields in the form and, in the end, if the user chose to, copy the data from the form fields back to the recordset.

Other times more complex solutions were required, as I would need to edit several pieces of data at once in continuous forms, "save" them, run more code, maybe add fields to hold the information originated from that processing and so on. I then learned about using temporary tables, but did not like it, since it tended to bloat the db. I even went on to creating temporary databases during code execution that would host the temporary tables and be destroyed in the end, but that added too much unnecessary complexity.

Nowadays I'm using disconnected ADO recordsets to hold the temporary data and fields. It works but has its limitations.

So I'm wondering, what is the best way you - much more experienced than me - guys use to approach this kind of scenario? Is using in memory ADO recordsets really the best way around?

Comment: The power of Access is the bound form. To save validated (full) data only, create a validate function and, in BeforeUpdate, set Cancel to True if validation fails. Feel free to prefer unbound forms, but then use another tool than Access, like Visual Studio and WinForms.

Comment: I developed a database to manage our user base and their usage permissions for our other dbs. There is a form in there to manage the permissions of a chosen user. In it, all of the relevant permissions are loaded and the manager can delete, create or edit the existent ones as much as needed. All of this happens in a temp table, so if the user closes the form without saving, nothing is changed. Could you tell me how would you approach this with a form bound to the "real" table?

Comment: You could wrap the update in a transaction. Then, if the form is closed without a commit, rollback the changes.

Comment: I'll do some research on how to do what you're suggesting, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two things that a form does that have completely different requirements. Editing existing records (and bound forms are great for that) and creating new records (where using a straight bound form can result in creating incomplete records). The way to approach it depends on many things but mainly to how much data is necessary for a new record to be considered "complete".

I usually do one of the following things:

- Create an unbound popup modal form for adding new records where only the necessary fields are present. Once complete it loads the new record to the main form for further editing.
- Use the above method except the form is not a popup one but a set of unbound fields in the footer or header of the main form.
- Let the user create new records but bind validation on the OnClose (and/or other appropriate to your situation) event of the form that deletes the half-filled record if it does not validate.
- Let users create new records in the bound form but have a 'cleanup' routine called either on a schedule or based on user actions.

Ultimately if your business process **requires** the majority of fields to be manually added/edited every time a new record is added **or edited**, you are better off using an unbound form.

Answer (score 0):

> This way, if the user opened a form, he had to complete all the steps
>   he was supposed to do, because if he closed the form mid process (or
>   the computer froze, or anything of the sort), the actual data would be
>   compromised as it would be half complete

No, if the computer freezes, then no data is saved to the table. This is the same if you used a disconnected reocrdset and a un-bound form.

If you use the before update event in the form that has some verification code and does a simple cancel = true, then the forms data is not saved nor is the table updated. Again, if you used a dis-connected record set and the user closes the form, you have to test the data – and again you can either choose to write out the data or not – this effect is ZERO difference from using a bound form to a table or a disconnected form.

> If the editions were simple, I discovered that I could create a
>   recordset, copy relevant data to unbound fields in the form and, in
>   the end, if the user chose to, copy the data from the form fields back
>   to the recordset.

No you don’t need to do the above. The above achieves nothing and only racks up additional development hours and increases cost of the application. In near all cases in-bound forms increase development costs over that of a simple form bound to a table. So the original developer had the correct idea. You can control the update of the underlying table in near all cases to achieve the required verification. Forms only save and write the data out if the developer allows as such.

So Access forms when bound no more or less write incomplete data out to a table if you place verification code in the forms before update event. A half-filled bound form, or a half filled un-bound form with dis-connected reocrdset BOTH will not write their data if the computer freezes.

And BOTH types of forms will not write out data to table until such time your verification code has completed.

Access is not designed for un-bound forms, and tools like vb.net, or even VB6 had a whole bunch of cool wizards and support for un-bound forms. In access, we don't have those wizards. And when you use UN-bound forms then you loose tons of form events. You in effect get the worst of both worlds, since you lose use of form events and have no wizards or support for un-bound. Even just the several delete record events we have are rather amazing.

You lose use of me.dirty, on-insert, me.newReocrd, forms after update events - the list of features you toss out and lose is huge. And if  you want a button to write data to the table (such as a save button on the form), then just go:

```
If me.Dirty = True then
   me.Dirty = False     ' this forces your verification code to run
End if
```

There are FEW use cases in which in-bound forms will benefit you, but they will cost you rather much in terms of development times.

Comment: Thank you for all this info. I'll look into all of it. As I said, I'm learning as I work, and by looking at what the other guy did. I ended thinking bound forms were "bad" because, as I'm beginning to realize now, he did not implement any method of verification at all... Picture a form with lots of fields bound to a table. User start filling the fields, as he moves from one to another, the previous gets updated and, with no sort of verification, "saved" to the table. If he closed the form mid way, information would be missing, possibly breaking the rest of the process chain.

Comment: So I've been trying to understand what you said... I'm beginning to understand how the form .Dirty works and I've made some progress setting  cancel = true on the form .BeforeUpdate event if a condition is met. It works to discard any changes in all fields of a single record, but when I try it with a continuous form, it only applies to the current record in focus, I cant "undo" changes made to previous records. I still don't understand how to "wrap" changes made to all records since the form was opened and "undo" them when the form is closed with a "cancel" button.

Comment: A form ONLY edits one record at a time. So don’t confuse that of any regular form (that edits one record at a time), or a continues form that AGAIN edits one record at a time but displays many records. The fact that you display more than one record or allow navigation of “many” records in a form that only displays one record changes NOTHING in regards to verifying that record. The exception to this setup is when such a “set” of data belongs to some parent form or parent record. That’s a different problem and there are several approaches to such problems.